# Phalcon php implode(): Invalid arguments passed in

Tags: php, phalcon

I am coding pagination.

Action logic:

```
$page = 0; 
$pages = 5; 
$language_id = 2; 

$links = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
    if ($i == $page) {
        $links = $i;
    } else {
        $link = $this->getBaseUrl() . '/v2/translate/' . 'lid/' . $language_id . '/page/' . $i;
        $links[] = '<a href="' . $link . '">' . $i . '</a>';

    }
}

$this->view->setVar('links', $links);
```

View logic

```
<div style="margin-top: 20px; font-size: 18px">
    Pages: <?= implode(' ', $links) ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you assign $links to view? Probably not...

Comment: @nospor Yes I assign

Comment: So display that value in view to see what is there, because at some point you assign there integer instead of array.... ` $links = $i;`

Answer (score 1):

Problem is not with Phalcon, but a silly error on your side :)

Check the following `if` statement:

```
if ($i == $page) {
    $links = $i;
}
```

In the last iteration of the loop you convert the `$links` array into an integer and then pass it to the view.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see `if($i == $page)` will never be true, because You never increment `$page` that You are setting to `0` at the beginning of Your code. Also, please tell us what version of Phalcon are You using and what view engine do You use.